# Web server cookie changes not working from iframe in Chrome with SameSite=None

Tags: cookies, iframe, session-cookies, samesite

I have a web app that is used in an iframe (it is a Word Office add-in).

The iframe app has a simple logout link (e.g., https://www.example.com/logout) to clear the session cookie.  This logout link:

- works outside of the iframe in all browsers
- works in the iframe in Safari and Firefox, but
- doesn't work in the iframe in Chrome even though I've set SameSite=None.

My session cookie has the following settings:

- Not permanent (though lasts a long time)
- SameSite=None
- Secure
- HttpOnly
- Domain is example.com instead of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) but I don't think this is the issue

Here is a screenshot in case you don't believe me :):
[image]

Googling for this returns a ton of hits recommending to set SameSite=None but I've already done that.

Any idea why the web server can't change the cookie from the iframe?

Comment: Have you resolved this? Having the exact same issue currently. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanPeters, my solution was to open a new browser window, clear the cookie in the new browser window, and then close the browser window. Not ideal but it works.